# Bytes position of a FindInFiles search in vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, byte, findinfiles

I am unable to set the position in bytes using FindInFiles search. Wouldn't it be conceivable to think that one could access the search position when the searched word is found?

Below is my search code through all the files in a directory in my application.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) Then
                Dim matches As String = Trim(TextBox1.Text).ToLower
                Dim list As System.Collections.ObjectModel.
      ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)

                list = My.Computer.FileSystem.FindInFiles(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Librairies\",
     matches, True, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)
                If list.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each filename In list
                        ListView1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename))
                        'ListView1.Items(0).SubItems.Add(FirstCharacter)
                    Next
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Aucun résultat.")
                End If
            End If
```

Comment: It's certainly conceivable but that's not what that `FindInFiles` method does. You can't make it do something that it doesn't. It just provides the paths of the matching files. If you want the actual position of the search term then you need to find that yourself. Keep in mind that you're doing a text search so it really depends on how the search is conducted. The position of text doesn't correspond directly to the position of the bytes representing that text.

Comment: Definitely jmcilhinney, thanks for your explanations.